# .config/git/ignore': Permission denied

Tags: git

I am trying to push an app to Heroku using the CLI. When I enter the command `git add .` in the terminal, I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/me/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
'/Users/me/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this same as yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end

Comment: @Sahan No. That question is about a remote server denying the push. This is about local file permissions.

Comment: What're the owner, group, and permissions on that attributes file?

Comment: I am the owner and I have read and write permissions on the file.

Comment: I believe this is the same error as https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995027/. basically if you run a command with sudo and it creates the .config directory then root becomes owner.  git then checks the .config (now its created and causes the error)

Answer (score 27):

Here's how I solved it:

1. In Terminal `cd` to the User director with `cd ~`.
2. Change the directory permissions with `sudo chmod 755 .config`
3. Enter your login password.

Comment: ‘`cd ~`’: Or just `cd`.

Answer (score 3):

use this command to solve this problem ( commit to git ):

```
sudo chown -R hamid /Users/hamid
```

after that enter your Mac login password and allow that's dialogs appear

take attention that hamid is my username and you should enter your username instead of that . You can use the below command to get your username:

```
id -un
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error messages outputting from git commands, though the usual set of git commands (pull, push, checkout, etc.) still worked just fine. `sudo chmod 755 /home/your-username-here/.config/` followed by entering your login password successfully changed the permission and got rid of the error messages. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932536/ftp-rights-755-vs-777/19547354)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @seanv507 in the comments section, the answer is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995027/2142093). The copy/pasta is:

```
cd ~/
ls -al
<Noticed .config was owned by root, unlike everything else in $HOME>
sudo chown -R $(whoami) .config
```

Answer (score 0):

While you might be the owner of the files, check the permission of the parent folders `.config`, `.config/git` ([as in here](https://adiyatmubarak.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/git-fix-warning-unable-to-access-configgitignore-permission-denied/))

And check if the session in which you push to Heroky has the right `HOME` anbd  `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R USER:(id -gn $USER) /Users/myusername/.config
```

The only thing that changed here was `myusername`; the other places where it mentioned `USER` were left the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the private ssh key to my SSH agent. I was able to do this through command line, then Git Kraken worked.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

"id_rsa" or whatever you have named your private key and public key pair that you have added to your github.

reference: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git config --global core.fileMode false
```

use this and then commit changes and then check the log it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Users/me/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
/Users/me/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
```

Solution:
For this go to terminal
just run command below :

```
sudo chmod 755 /Users/your-username/.config
```

in your case it will be :

```
sudo chmod 755 /Users/me/.config
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/dir worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).